# Win7 Getting blue screen Crash, how to check if its software or hardware . (WinDbg log included)

Tags: windows-7, crash, windbg

suddenly my old win 7 64 bit started to crash with blue screen . 
i want to know what is the problem . 
i did !analize on the mini dmp file. and here is the result , unfortunately i have problem to understand what is the problem . 
here is the log :

```
ADDITIONAL_DEBUG_TEXT:  
Use '!findthebuild' command to search for the target build information.
If the build information is available, run '!findthebuild -s ; .reload' to set symbol path and load symbols.

    MODULE_NAME: nt

    FAULTING_MODULE: fffff80003651000 nt

    DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  521ea035

    BUGCHECK_STR:  0x1a_41790

    CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

    DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  VISTA_DRIVER_FAULT

    CURRENT_IRQL:  0

    LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff80003737d50 to fffff800036c6bc0

    STACK_TEXT:  
    fffff880`0ac34818 fffff800`03737d50 : 00000000`0000001a 00000000`00041790 fffffa80`01bbd6c0 00000000`0000ffff : nt+0x75bc0
    fffff880`0ac34820 00000000`0000001a : 00000000`00041790 fffffa80`01bbd6c0 00000000`0000ffff 00000000`00000000 : nt+0xe6d50
    fffff880`0ac34828 00000000`00041790 : fffffa80`01bbd6c0 00000000`0000ffff 00000000`00000000 00000000`00d11000 : 0x1a
    fffff880`0ac34830 fffffa80`01bbd6c0 : 00000000`0000ffff 00000000`00000000 00000000`00d11000 fffffa80`09e0a060 : 0x41790
    fffff880`0ac34838 00000000`0000ffff : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00d11000 fffffa80`09e0a060 00000000`00000000 : 0xfffffa80`01bbd6c0
    fffff880`0ac34840 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00d11000 fffffa80`09e0a060 00000000`00000000 fffff680`00069ff8 : 0xffff


    STACK_COMMAND:  kb

    FOLLOWUP_IP: 
    nt+75bc0
    fffff800`036c6bc0 48894c2408      mov     qword ptr [rsp+8],rcx

    SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  0

    SYMBOL_NAME:  nt+75bc0

    FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

    IMAGE_NAME:  ntoskrnl.exe

    BUCKET_ID:  WRONG_SYMBOLS

    Followup: MachineOwner
    ---------
```

i also have sysdata.xml log but it is long and i didn't find any Crash info 
How can i check if it is hardware or driver problem ?

link to minidmp and the xml code :
https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ezl5bx9raddy4p/windb.zip?dl=0

Also please take a look at the result of memtest86+: 
[image]

Comment: this text is useless. you forgot to fetch the debug symbols. share (onedrive share link) the actual dmp file + the XML

Comment: here is the link thanks!
https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ezl5bx9raddy4p/windb.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA (50)
Invalid system memory was referenced.  This cannot be protected by try-except.
Typically the address is just plain bad or it is pointing at freed memory.
Arguments:
Arg1: fffffa83017b348b, memory referenced.
Arg2: 0000000000000000, value 0 = read operation, 1 = write operation.
Arg3: fffff8000367d8b5, If non-zero, the instruction address which referenced the bad memory
    address.
Arg4: 0000000000000005, (reserved)

Debugging Details:
------------------


Could not read faulting driver name

STACK_TEXT:
00 nt!KeBugCheckEx
01 nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'
02 nt!KiPageFault
03 nt!MiAgeWorkingSet
04 nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'
05 nt!MmWorkingSetManager
06 nt!KeBalanceSetManager
07 nt!PspSystemThreadStartup
08 nt!KxStartSystemThread

IMAGE_NAME:  memory_corruption

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x50_nt!MiAgeWorkingSet+52b

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x50_nt!MiAgeWorkingSet+52b

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  X64_0x50_nt!MiAgeWorkingSet+52b
```

The `memory_corruption` at `nt!MiAgeWorkingSet+52b` looks like a memory/RAM related crash.

You use the `F1` BIOS/UEFI:

```
BiosVersion = F1
BiosReleaseDate = 08/19/2014
SystemManufacturer = Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
SystemProductName = H81M-S2H
```

[update to F2](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=5158#bios) and look what happens. If you still get crashes, test eahc RAM stick alone with [memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/). If both are fine alone, the mixing of a Transcend and Team-Elite RAM module could cause the crash.

Comment: Thanks allot !!! 
what does "mixing of a Transcend and Team-Elite RAM module could cause the crash." means?

Comment: you use 2 different RAM modules from 2 manufacturers and this can cause stability issues. Try to use a Kit with RAM modules from the same manufacture.

Comment: Thanks , you are right it is 2 manufactures , but it worked fine 2 years almost , so iguess something broke there

Comment: hey i updated the results of memtest86+ , i have no idea what it means 
This is after 3 hours

Comment: you have 22 errors. So the RAM module that you tested is damaged and should be removed

Comment: thanks , but what is the RAM i tested ? i dont see its name ,also where do you see 22 errors ?

Comment: that's why I told you to remove 1 RAM module and test each one alone. In the picture you see that you ran 3 passes and get 22 errors.